# Yarn equivalent of `npm access`

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

What is the yarn equivalent of the `npm access` command? I want to grant a team write permissions to a package I am publishing to NPM via `yarn publish`. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like this simply does not exist yet. I (or someone else) can add an answer to this question once an equivalent command has been added to the Yarn project.